# Tim Sort Error in Compare Method in Java 7

Tags: java, timsort

I just wrote a test program to violate the transitivity in compareTo method of Java 7 which uses Tim Sort. Below is the implementation for my compare.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(ComparableObject o) {
    if (o.getId() != 0 && this.getId() != 0) {
        if (o.getId() < this.getId()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o.getId() > this.getId()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

As expected it throws the following exception when I try to run the program as it violates transitivity -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeLo(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:24)
```

What is the best way to check for zero(for integers) or null(for String or any other Object) values and compare the 2 elements only if they are not zero or null without getting the Tim Sort exception? How can I write the above code so that I don't get the error but compare only non-zero integers?

Comment: You _absolutely must_ decide a way to compare zero to other things.  You can sort them into a different position from everything else, but you can't just give up on sorting them.

Comment: What about nulls? Strings can be null. Do I need to consider those like zero while sorting too?

Comment: Consider what happens for (-1, 0) and (0, -1) as input...

Comment: If null is a thing that can happen in your input, you will need to decide how they get sorted.  If nulls are a thing that _shouldn't_ happen in your input, then throwing `NullPointerException` is a valid decision.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I see the point why it throws the exception. But the question is in case of Strings, I don't want to compare the null string(s). If I check for null instead of zero I will get a similar exception. What is the best way to check for null values without getting the exception?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks. That makes sense!

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you can just use `nullsFirst(Comparator)` to declare that nulls are less than everything else.  Otherwise, you'll need to inline that logic directly: check if the first one is null and check if the second is null, separately.